# Delete key under iOS with Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, ios, key-binding

I use the Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard with an iOS device (iPhone SE running iOS 10.3.2). I am trying to get the *Delete* key to work.

I read on [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/A/2/7A2A35DD-7FA8-4EAC-8A41-F47884AB8783/TDS_UniversalFoldableKeyboard.pdf) data sheet that with the iOS key binding, *Delete* can be used by combining *Fn* and *Backspace*. However, in iOS mode the *Fn* key is mapped to *Cmd*, so that pressing *Fn*/*Cmd* and *Backspace* at the same time causes a "delete the current line" rather than a proper "Delete" for me.

Any idea on how to get this to work? Many thanks!